# how to divide the work on MPI-Processes GameOfLife C++

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

I've bin struggeling for a while with MPI and i am not able to Parallelize GameOfLife in c++ using MPI .
i dont really understand how will i divide the work for each Process , and how will every Process do its work i think i've reached a close End here .

the first block is where the root process initiallize 2D-Array , print it and then send for each process its own part of the work(at least i think so) left elements will be given to the last process .

```
>>>>
   if(rank==0){

    for (int h = 0; h < ROWS; h++){
       for (int w = 0; w <COLS ; w++){
         currentWorld[h][w] = (double(rand()) / RAND_MAX < 0.1) ? 'X' :'.';
       }
     }

    //Recieve subarrays and gather them to be printed
    //char recieve_array[][]; 
      
      for (int h = 0; h < ROWS; h++){ // if the iterate starts before rank zero this Code Block will lead to print that array every time we start iterating and that will lead to faulse results
     
         for (int w = 0; w <COLS ; w++){             
           std::cout<<currentWorld[h][w];
         }
       }
       char send_array[elements_per_process][COLS]; //create the array that will be sent to each Process
       int counter=0;
       int rankNum=1;

       for(int i=0;i<ROWS;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<COLS;j++){
            send_array[counter][j]=currentWorld[i][j];// send_array which will be send will be from 0 to elements_per_process -1
           }
         //when the first array is full that condition will be executed(counter+1==elements_per_process),counter set to zero and then prepare the next array
         if(counter+1==elements_per_process)// from zero to elemens_per_process-1
           {                  
               //those sends goes to every Process with his part of array to work on it , with Tag 10
            MPI_Send(&elements_per_process,1,MPI_INT,rankNum,10,MPI_COMM_WORLD);//send the divided work for each Process
            MPI_Send(&send_array,COLS*elements_per_process,MPI_CHAR,rankNum,10,MPI_COMM_WORLD);//send the divided work for each Process
            rankNum++;
            counter=0;
            if(left_elements>0 && rankNum==size-1)
            { //last process deal with the Reminder    
               int left_elements=ROWS-(elements_per_process*size)
               MPI_Send(&left_elements,1,MPI_INT,rankNum,10,MPI_COMM_WORLD);//send the divided work for each Process
               MPI_Send(&send_array,COLS*left_elements,MPI_CHAR,rankNum,10,MPI_COMM_WORLD);//send the divided work for each Process
             }            
            }
         else{
               counter++;
             }          
          }     
        }
```

in the second  Block i am trying to recieve from each process its own part of work which sent by the root and then count the Neighbors alive to set the next generation
so when i recieve those parts , should i iterate through those subarrays or through the whole original array and each process will just know its own part ? and at the end what should i send back ? the new subarrays from each process to root process , or the new whole array ? i think thats my problem for now , any thing will help because its hard to find some thing that could explain that(if any one knows any resource that could help i will be thankfull)

```
>>>>
         if(rank!=0) {        
                  //                     Determine the uppder and lower Neighbor for every Processe          //
  int upperNeighbor = (rank == 1) ? size - 1 : rank-1; //determine the upper rank Neighbor
  int lowerNeighbor = (rank == size) ? 1 : rank + 1;//determine the lowerNeighbor
  char recieved_array[elements_per_process][COLS];
     
         //Process Recieve his part of work from root Process
         //Process Recieve needed Data from other Processes(if the cell is at the top/bottom of Process then it needs data from the next/previous Process)
         //Tag for thoose Recieves will be 10
  MPI_Recv(&elements_per_process,1,MPI_INT,0,10,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
  MPI_Recv(&recieved_array,elements_per_process*COLS,MPI_CHAR,0,10,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);

         //send top row above
  MPI_Send(&currentWorld[1][0], COLS, MPI_CHAR, upperNeighbor,20,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    
    //send bottom row below
  MPI_Send(&currentWorld[elements_per_process][0], COLS, MPI_CHAR, lowerNeighbor, 30, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    //recieve bottom row from below
  MPI_Recv(&currentWorld[elements_per_process + 1][0],COLS, MPI_CHAR, lowerNeighbor,30, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);

    //recieve top row from above
  MPI_Recv(&currentWorld[0][0], COLS, MPI_CHAR, upperNeighbor, 20, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);

  int neighbors=0;
  for(int i=0;i<ROWS;i++){// originally for(int i=0;i<elements_per_process;i++)           
    for(int j=0;i<COLS;j++) {
      if(J==0||j==COL-1){
        if(j==0){// J==0 
            // check Neighbors but ignoring the left column
          for (int rows = i - 1; rows <=i+ 1; rows++){ //from -1 untill 1                           
            for (int cols = j + 1; cols <= j + 1; cols++){//from -1 untill 1                              
              if (i == rows && j == cols)
              {
                continue;
              }
               if (i > -1 && i < ROWS && j > -1 && j < COLS){
                 if (recieved_array[i][j] == 'X'){
                   neighbors++;  
                          }
                        } 
                    }
               }
                    }//J==0
         else{ //check the Neighbours but ignoring the right column(COL-1)                            
           for (int rows = i - 1; rows <=i+ 1; rows++){ //from -1 untill 1                               
             for (int cols = j + 1; cols <= j + 1; cols++){//from -1 untill 1                                      
               if (i == rows && j == cols)
               {
                  continue;
               }
               if (i > -1 && i < ROWS && j > -1 && j < COLS){
                 if (recieved_array[i][j] == 'X'){
                   neighbors++;  
                            }
                         } 
                        }
                      }                              
                    }
                 } 
        else//if(j!=0 && j!=COL-1){                             
           for (int rows2 = i - 1; rows2 <=i+ 1; rows2++){ //from -1 untill 1                         
             for (int cols2 = j + 1; cols2 <= j + 1; cols2++){//from -1 untill 1                              
               if (i == rows2 && j == cols2)
               {
                  continue;
               }
               if (i > -1 && i < ROWS && j > -1 && j < COLS){
                 if (recieved_array[i][j] == 'X'){
                   neighbors++; 
                   }
                } 
              }
             }                
            }
          }
         }
        }
```

Comment: 1. you should not generate the board on process zero: do everything distributed. 2. send and receive are blocking calls so your code probably deadlocks. 3. fix your indentation. this is unreadable.

Comment: thanks for your answer
i think i have problem in understanding how the MPI exactly works because of that i am facing such problems , i made the indentation alittle bit better i guess but still i cant get the idea , how should i distribute the work on every process and how should i collect the finished work from each processe , i cant get that point

Comment: The game of life is basically a stencil operation. There are a million MPI tutorials that have stencil operations as example. Search for "Poisson problem" or "heat equation".